# Chart js Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext') while I destroy on progress

Tags: vue.js, charts, vuejs3, chart.js

I am using vue 3.0 and chart.js

I am using a lot of bar, line charts and have to change their labels, data shortly with button.
so I am using API(destroy) such as:

```html
    <div ref="chartDOMContainer">
      <canvas class="canvas" ref="chartDOM" />
    </div>
```

```js
const chartDOM = ref();
const chartDOMContainer = ref();
const barChart = ref();

const redrawChart = async () => {
  if (Chart.getChart(chartDOM.value)) {
     barChart.value.destroy();
     barChart.value = new Chart(chartDOM.value.getContext("2d"), config.value);
     isRdy.value = true;
  }
};


nextTick(() => {
  chartDOMContainer.value.style.width = width.value;
  chartDOMContainer.value.style.height = height.value;

  barChart.value = new Chart(chartDOM.value.getContext("2d"), config.value);
  Chart.register(BarController, BarElement, ChartDataLabels);
});
```

I set chart js animation duration as 500 ms.

and if i click buttons in less than 500ms(in very short time,),
I get "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')" error.

so I tried using async, await but obviously it didnt work.

i really would like to know what should i do to avoid this error without setting animation duration to 0. :(

Comment: Probably the problem is that you're destroying an instance instead of updating existing one